# How to capture brackets with variable in-between amount of space as a single group?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, pcre, regex-group

Suppose I have the following text:

```
Yes: [x]
Yes: [  x]
Yes: [x  ]
Yes: [  x  ]
No: [
No: ]
```

I am interested in capturing the angular brackets `[` and `]` containing an `x` with a variable amount of horizontal space on either side of the `x`. The bit I am struggling with is that **both angular brackets must be captured into a group with the same `ID` (i.e., `$1`)**.

I started with a combination of positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions using the following `regex`:

```
\[(?=\h*x)|(?<=x)\h*\K\]
```

Which produces the following matches (i.e., see <kbd>[demo](https://regex101.com/r/v6zH2m/1/)</kbd> with the `extended` flag enabled for clarity):

[image: Example first attempt]

Then, I tried placing a capturing group around the whole expression, but the match extends to the horizontal space after the positive lookbehind `(?<=x)\h*` as shown below (i.e., also see <kbd>[demo](https://regex101.com/r/v6zH2m/2/)</kbd>).

[image: Example second attempt]

I am using [Oniguruma regular expressions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars) and the [`PCRE`](https://www.pcre.org) flavor. Do you have any ideas if and how this can be done?

Comment: This is not possible in any regex flavor, as you cannot place disjoint streaks of text into a single capturing group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks, that explains a lot of things...

Comment: You might use a branch reset group with an alternation `(?|(\[)(?=\h*x\h*])|(?<=\[)\h*x\h*(]))` https://regex101.com/r/R8OFr9/1 It would be the same group but a different match.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, this is exactly what I have been looking for! Superb! Would it be possible to explain a bit the alternation approach in an answer? Then I can also accept it!

Comment: So, "both angular brackets must be part of this capturing group" is wrong? Did you mean to write "both angular brackets must be captured into a group with the same ID"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes you are right, that is what I meant. I apologized for the misuse of terminology. I will correct the mistake in the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the other question. Unfortunately, the title of that question is too specific and did not show on my radar while searching for a solution.

Comment: That duplicate is too broad for a specific question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
(?|(\[)(?=\h*x\h*])|(?<=\[)\h*x\h*(]))
```

- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `(\[)(?=\h*x\h*])` Capture `[` in group 1, asserting `x` between optional horizontal whitespace chars to the right followed by `]`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\[)\h*x\h*(])` Assert `[` to the left, then match `x` between optional horizontal whitespace and capture `]` in group 2
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8OFr9/1/)

Comment: I know it's not in line with the guidelines, but thank you, this is a powerful approach to be aware of.